# Adding a subdirectory to a URL using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, subdirectory

I am trying to achieve the following:

This URL: `www.example.com/wis/9-3/1998/0.general`

Redirected to this URL: `www.example.com/9440/wis/9-3/1998/0.general`

So I'm trying to add this subdirectory to the target URL:  `/9400/`

Also, `/0.general` changes, so that needs to be obtained from the original URL.

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/wis/9-3/1998/(.*)$ /9400/wis/9-3/1998/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `/0.general changes` <- Is this a subdirectory or file, and does the format for the name remain consistent (e.g., a digit followed by a period and then a word)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/wis/9-3/1998/(.*)$ /9400/wis/9-3/1998/$1 [L]
> ```

This won't work in a *directory* (or `.htaccess`) context because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In `.htaccess` only a partial URL-path is matched, which notably does not start with a slash. So, this should be written:

```
RewriteRule ^wis/9-3/1998/(.*) /9400/wis/9-3/1998/$1 [L]
```

(The end `$` is superfluous since regex is greedy by default.)

Note also that this is an *internal rewrite*, not an *external "redirect"*, as you've stated in your question. (Although an *internal rewrite* might well be what you require?)

Note also, @dan's comment above. Generally, the regex should be as *specific* as possible.

You could also "simplify" the above directive to save repetition:

```
RewriteRule ^(wis/9-3/1998/.*) /9400/$1 [L]
```

---

> **UPDATE#1:** Within my htaccess I have some default wordpress expressions

If this is WordPress the you can't perform this type of *internal rewrite* in `.htaccess` - because of the way WordPress routes the URLs (it looks at the requested URL, to the rewritten URL).

However, you *can* use an *external redirect* (ie. the URL changes). In which, case this should go at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteRule ^(wis/9-3/1998/.*) /9400/$1 [R,L]
```

Note the addition of the `R` flag. (This is a temporary 302 redirect.)

> **UPDATE#2:** is there a way to include a range where 1998 is located. Let's say from 1998 to 2005

Regex is not very good for doing "ranges", however, since you have a fairly limited range you can use *alternation* and include each possible value: 1998, 1999, 2000, etc.:

```
RewriteRule ^(wis/9-3/(?:1998|1999|2000|2001|2003|2003|2004|2005)/.*) /9400/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried out both of above solutions and it didn't work. Within my htaccess I have some default wordpress expressions and I start the file with RewriteEngine On

Comment: "I have some default wordpress expressions" - Ah, if this is WordPress then you can't use `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL in this way (because of the way WP routes URLs) - you need to do this in WordPress itself. However, you _can_ use a redirect - is a redirect what you require? I'll update my answer...

Comment: After reading up on 301 vs 302, I rather have 301 since the redirect is permanent. Do I amend your answer to `RewriteRule ^(wis/9-3/1998/.*) /9400/$1 [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But you should always test with a temporary redirect first to avoid caching issues.

Comment: excellent, thank you.
is there a way to include a range where `1998` is located. Let's say from 1998 to 2005.

Comment: Regex is not very good for "ranges", however, there is a way. I've updated my answer.